# Installing SSL in nginx problems

Tags: ssl, nginx

So I'm having trouble getting my ssl cert working properly in a rails app with nginx.  Do I need to use the sites-available folder, or can I just stick all my cert info in the /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf file?  Currently, my nginx.conf file looks like this, but when I try to access the site using https it doesn't work.  Before this, I have another server block that listens on port 80, and that works for http, but this one for https doesn't work.  Any ideas?

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.mysite.com;
#localhost;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate reference to my pem file
    ssl_certificate_key reference to my key file
    root reference to app in /var/www

#    ssl                  on;
#    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
#    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

#    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

#    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
#    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
#    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

#    location / {
#        root   html;
#        index  index.html index.htm;
#    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent a lot of time today setting up SSL on nginx.  First thing I would suggest checking is that port 443 is open from something like www.checkmyports.net

Also, do you get an error when you restart nginx?

Comment: I had figured this out, and yes, it was port 443.  Accepting answer :).

Comment: Dude I just wasted 3 hours trying to reconfigure my nginx to get ssl requests working and 443 was closed the whole time. If I could give you ten upvotes I'd do it.